# Disk usage on another filesystem

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

I have a directory on my ext4 partition with lots of rather small files. How can I figure out how much space would they use if I copy them to a file system with another cluster size (without actually copying them)? Like a FAT16 with 32KB cluster size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bash/awk script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '
    function ceil(number) {
        if (number == int(number)) {
            return (number);
        }
        return int(number) + 1;
    }

    function ceilWithUnit(number, unit) {
        return ceil(number / unit) * unit;
    }

    BEGIN {
        blockSize = 32 * 1024;
        fileSizeSum = 0;
        diskUsage = 0;
    }
    {
        diskUsage += ceilWithUnit($0, blockSize);
        fileSizeSum += $0;
    }
    END {
        printf("File count: %u\n", NR);
        printf("Average size: %.2f KB\n", fileSizeSum / NR / 1024);
        printf("Disk usage with %d bytes blocks: %.2f MB\n", blockSize, diskUsage / 1024 / 1024);
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if there is a specific tool for that, but if I'd really want to figure it out, I'd make something like (in a script/program, of course) : count the files and multiplicate that by the cluster size. Of course, I would need to check their "range" (I mean see their size and check if it would take 4, 8, 32 or 64 KB cluster-wise).

It's just an idea, I very well could be wrong. But unless someone else know a program that does it for you, you could at least work easily enough on an estimate.